# Rotate A user control very slowly

Tags: winrt-xaml, expression-blend, windows-rt

I have developed a user control for my windows 8.1 app. I want to rotate the control at a certain angle may me 180 degrees .
I am using RotateTransform and the image is rotating at one go !! I want a smooth rotation and the complete rotation should happen in 1 sec.

Above is the image of my user control 
[image: The user control when it is active.It appears on long tap of finger and is always above the finger]

The image rotates only when the tapped point is very near to image boundary !
when my finger reaches the image boundry , the control should keep itself inside the image so it would rotate

Have this [video](https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=0Ie1Z-vk4aE) link for your reference. I have to develop exactly like this.This is my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895307/overriding-manipulation-delta-of-a-user-control)

Comment: Put the rotation in a Storyboard with a Duration set to 00:00:01

Comment: Chris , any sample code ? The control has to rotate very smoothly at the edges of the screen .check the video for that